Pass RTSP stream with bounding boxes - how to improve latency on RTSP server pipeline?
I want to search for objects in incoming RTSP stream & add bounding boxes with cv2. The edited frames are pushed into GStreamer pipeline for GstRtspServer when a client is requesting data (to publish a rtsp stream output of the analyzed images). The code is runing on a Raspberry Pi 4.
The code is based on this thread and modified to my needs.
The code itself works, when opening rtsp://192.168.144.32:8555/test on a client in the network (like VLC on a laptop) the stream is shown.
Unfortunatly my usecase is time-critical and the latency still is about 1-2 seconds (I know about the VLC buffering delay, set it to 300ms).
When I print my incoming images directly to the screen (before pushing them in the pipeline) the latency is barely noticable (so less than 300ms). The processing (e.g. adding bounding boxes) does not affect the latency.
Additionaly, the playback depends on the player. VLC is doing okay (but lagging the first ~8s) while others like an android app showing green screen or a python script showing the stream slowed-down dont work as expected!
Somehow the pipeline output / encoding of the videostream is causing this behaviour.
Here is the code (object detection replaced by white frame):
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import gi
import numpy as np
import threading
import queue

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstRtspServer', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GstRtspServer, GLib

Gst.init(None)

class SensorFactory(GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory):
    def __init__(self, **properties):
        super(SensorFactory, self).__init__(**properties)
        
        # Initialize VideoCapture and start the stream
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.144.25:8554/main.264")  # incoming RTSP stream URL
        if not self.cap.isOpened():
            print('Error opening the RTSP stream.')

        self.number_frames = 0
        self.fps = 30
        self.duration = Gst.SECOND / self.fps
        
        # Buffer for the current frame
        self.current_frame = None
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

        # Background thread for continuously reading the stream
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.read_stream)
        self.thread.start()

        # GStreamer pipeline
        self.launch_string = 'appsrc name=source is-live=true block=true format=GST_FORMAT_TIME ' \
                             'caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1280,height=720,framerate={}/1 ' \
                             '! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=NV12 ' \
                             '! queue max-size-buffers=10 ' \
                             '! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency ' \
                             '! rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0 pt=96'.format(self.fps)

        print('SensorFactory initialized.')

    def read_stream(self):
        print('Stream reader thread started.')
        while not self.stop_event.is_set():
            if not self.cap.isOpened():
                self.cap.open("rtsp://192.168.144.25:8554/main.264")  # Attempt reconnection
                if not self.cap.isOpened():
                    print('Error opening the RTSP stream.')
                    continue

            ret, frame = self.cap.read()
            if not ret:
                print('Error reading the stream.')
                continue

            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (1280, 720))
            
            # Draw rectangle
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (20, 20), (1260, 700), (255, 255, 255), 1)

            with self.lock:
                self.current_frame = frame.copy()  # Save the frame

    def on_need_data(self, src, length):
        with self.lock:
            if self.current_frame is None:
                print('No frame available.')
                return

            frame = self.current_frame

        # Convert frame to GStreamer buffer
        data = frame.tobytes()
        buf = Gst.Buffer.new_allocate(None, len(data), None)
        buf.fill(0, data)
        buf.duration = self.duration
        timestamp = self.number_frames * self.duration
        buf.pts = buf.dts = int(timestamp)
        buf.offset = int(timestamp)
        self.number_frames += 1
        retval = src.emit('push-buffer', buf)
        if retval != Gst.FlowReturn.OK:
            print('Error pushing buffer:', retval)

    def do_create_element(self, url):
        return Gst.parse_launch(self.launch_string)

    def do_configure(self, rtsp_media):
        self.number_frames = 0
        appsrc = rtsp_media.get_element().get_child_by_name('source')
        appsrc.connect('need-data', self.on_need_data)
        print('New client connected.')

    def stop(self):
        print('Stopping SensorFactory...')
        self.stop_event.set()
        self.thread.join()
        self.cap.release()
        print('SensorFactory stopped.')

class GstServer(GstRtspServer.RTSPServer):
    def __init__(self, **properties):
        super(GstServer, self).__init__(**properties)
        self.factory = SensorFactory()
        self.factory.set_shared(True)
        self.get_mount_points().add_factory("/test", self.factory)
        self.set_address('0.0.0.0')
        self.set_service('8555')
        self.attach(None)

        print(f'Server started. Available at rtsp://192.168.144.32:8555/test')

    def stop(self):
        self.factory.stop()
        super(GstServer, self).stop()
        print('GstServer stopped.')

def main():
    server = GstServer()
    loop = GLib.MainLoop()
    try:
        loop.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Server stopping...")
        server.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


I tried several things:

leave the incoming rtsp stream opened (independent from client connection) made a huge improvement in playback offset somehow - I think the buffer was not cleared upon client connection so I saw video from 30s ago.
lowering the resolution of the whole system only affects CPU load, not the latency.
speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency made it much faster but still with the 1-2s latency.

My goal is to reduce the latency nearly as low as on the preview (before pushing into the pipeline).
I´m not an expert with GStreamer and python in general, just trying to get things as good and stable as possible :)
